# Angular cdkStepper skip and load the second step

Tags: angular, stepper

In my angular application I am using CdkStepper to steps thru between 2 different steps.
I call this.cdkStepper.next(); on click of a button to go to next step. This works fine.

In another scenario, on click of a button from some component(not included in stepper),
I call this stepper1, don't load the stepper1, but actually call the step2 by calling next().
I get an error, Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'next'), it is not able to find the cdkStepper.
How can we call cdkStepper.next()  to load the second step with out loading the step1.

**stepper.component.html**

```
<app-stepper #cdkStepper [linear]="true">
  <cdk-step >
        <button  (click)="next()" > NEXT </button>
  </cdk-step>
  <cdk-step>
        <app-component-2>
        </app-component-2>
  </cdk-step>
</app-stepper>
```

**stepper.component.ts**

```
export class StepperComponent implements OnInit {
    ngOnInit(): void {
       this.next();
    }
    public next(): void {     
       this.cdkStepper.next();
    }
}
```

**app-component-2.html**

```
<div>
    This is my step2
</div>
```

Comment: Put an ngIf on the step1 that points to a false (or true when needed)